# Selecting queue based on dynamic index in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I have n_slots (constant) queues and a TensorFlow graph where I would like to enqueue or dequeue from the queue at index "slot". Slot is a dynamic index, int32 tensor with shape [].

I can't think of a way to do this without resorting to ugly/inefficient while loops or nested cond's. (Imagine if n_slots is 10000 for example, the operation should still be O(1).)

For example, let the following be a tensor graph:

```
n_slots = 4
queues = [None] * n_slots
for i in range(n_slots):
    queues[i] = tf.FIFOQueue(5, [tf.float32], shapes=[[]])

queue = queues[2]
assert isinstance(queue, tf.FIFOQueue)
enqueue_op = queue.enqueue([5])

with tf.control_dependencies([enqueue_op]):
    dq_ops = [None] * n_slots
    for i in range(n_slots):
        dq_ops[i] = queues[i].dequeue()
    dq_ops = tf.convert_to_tensor(dq_ops)

    slot = tf.convert_to_tensor(2)
    out = dq_ops[slot]
```

Now when later executed (`print(sess.run(out)`) the operation will hang, because dq_ops needs to be fully evaluated before the index operation, so all side effects will execute before the index can be taken.

How would you do this dequeue correctly (without unintentional side effects) and efficiently (no while loops or nested conds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`tf.QueueBase.from_list()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/QueueBase#from_list) method handles this case. To dequeue from the queue at index `slot` in your list `queues`:

```
element = tf.QueueBase.from_list(slot, queues)
```

Comment: Thanks, I assumed there where a more general way to do this. Like a lazy partial tensor or something that doesn't evaluate it's slice dependencies until they are needed. So I didn't think about reading the QueueBase documentation more carefully. But this definitely solves my problem.

Comment: The more general way would be to use some control flow operations (e.g. `tf.cond()` or `tf.case()`) to wrap the dequeuing operations. However, I think `QueueBase.from_list()` was added before control flow support existed.